# Keeping URL variables when switching tabs

Tags: jquery, url, parameters, tabs

I'm using jquery ui tabs to switch between tabs on a page at http://www.code7dev4.co.uk/data

The relevant jquery code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function activateTab($tab) {
        var $activeTab = $tab.closest('dl').find('a.active'),
            contentLocation = $tab.attr("href") + 'Tab';

        // Strip off the current url that IE adds
        contentLocation = contentLocation.replace(/^.+#/, '#');

        //Make Tab Active
        $activeTab.removeClass('active');
        $tab.addClass('active');

        //Show Tab Content
        $(contentLocation).closest('.tabs-content').children('li').hide();
        $(contentLocation).css('display', 'block');
    }

    $('dl.tabs dd a').live('click', function (event) {
        activateTab($(this));
    });

    if (window.location.hash) {
        activateTab($('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]'));
        $.foundation.customForms.appendCustomMarkup();
    }
});
```

Now, the client needs the form on the right to create unique urls for each data search, and these are in the url as parameters (eg. http://www.code7dev4.co.uk/data?form_send=send&country=Uganda&sector=health&strail=plac&units=DollarConstant&year=2009).

Switching tabs loses the url variables and I'm left with `/data#table`.

How can I change the code so that those url parameters are maintained?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a base URL using the following:

```
<base href="http://www.code7dev4.co.uk/data">
```

This is throwing off the fragment identifier as it loads http://www.code7dev4.co.uk/data#id instead of just appending to the current URL (which includes the query string). This means the query string is being removed, and more importantly **reloading the page** (which defeats the entire purpose of the non-reloading tab switching).

Removing the base tag fixes the issue, but I'm not sure what impact that will have elsewhere.

**Update**

So below is the only solution I could find to "fix" the issue you are dealing wtih. It is very much here as an exercise, as I recommend not using this technique - it's inelegant and hasn't been tested in anything other than Chrome v23. Effectively, we're deactivating the `base` element by re-writing the `href` attribute during the `click` event on the anchor (this would correspond to the tabs on your page). We then reset the original `href` 20 milliseconds after the `mouseup` event. We have to build in the delay, as the `mouseup` event fires *before* the click event.

```
var anchor = document.querySelector("a"),
    baseElement = document.querySelector("base"),
    baseHref = baseElement.getAttribute("href");

    anchor.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        baseElement.setAttribute("href", "");
    }, true);

    anchor.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector("base").setAttribute("href", baseHref);
        }, 20);
    }, true);
```

The best solution is simply *not to use a `base` tag*, but if you don't have control over HTML output, this might just save the day at a pinch. I'd really like to see if anyone else comes up with a better (i.e. more elegant) solution.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I assume this base URL is being used for part of Joomla's functionality. Rather than remove this, which may cause issues on other pages, can you suggest a change to the js code above to grab the full url with params and use that rather than the base url? I know there's document.URL I can use in js but I can't tell where I need to set this. Basically override the url being appended. Is this an option? JS is not my strength, so your advice is appreciated.